# Oracle subpartition by reference: not supported, can it be emulated?

Tags: oracle

Given an address table with millions of entries, partitioned by state_cd:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESSES
(
    ADDRESS_ID  INT            NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    STATE_CD    VARCHAR2(2)    NOT NULL,
    CITY        VARCHAR2(100)  NOT NULL
) 
PARTITION BY LIST(STATE_CD) 
    (PARTITION P_AL VALUES ('AL'),...., PARTITION P_WY VALUES ('WY'));
```

And a measurements table with millions of measurements per day, range-partitioned by date:

```
CREATE TABLE MEASUREMENTS
(
    MEASUREMENT_ID INT    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MEASUREMENT_DT DATE   NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS_ID     INT    NOT NULL,
    MEASUREMENT    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MEASUREMENTS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID)
            REFERENCES ADDRESSES (ADDRESS_ID)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (MEASUREMENT_DT) 
(PARTITION P_20150101 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2015-01-02'),...);
```

Many queries would be greatly improved with partition-wise joining of MEASUREMENTS and ADDRESSES, e.g.:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(MEASUREMENT_DT) MNTH,
        CITY, 
        AVG(MEASUREMENT)
FROM    MEASUREMENTS 
        JOIN ADDRESSES USING (ADDRESS_ID)
GROUP BY TRUNC(MEASUREMENT_DT), CITY;
```

However, adding STATE_CD to MEASUREMENTS is an unacceptable violation of normal form (introducing entirely new performance issues, e.g. `ADDRESSES JOIN MEASUREMENTS USING (ADDRESS_ID, STATE_CD)` really messes with the CBO's cardinality estimates).

Optimal solution would be sub-partitioning by reference, which Oracle does not support: `CREATE TABLE MEASUREMENTS ... PARTITION BY RANGE(MEASUREMENT_DT) SUBPARTITION BY REFERENCE (MEASUREMENTS_FK1)`.

This seems like it'd be a fairly straightforward application of reference partitioning.  But not only is the syntax not supported; I wasn't able to find a lot of forum activity clamoring for such a feature.  This led to my posting here: typically when I am looking for a feature that no one else is looking for, it means I've overlooked an equivalent (or potentially even better) alternative.

Comment: With your example query you are joining all the measurements to all the addresses, so probably 2 full table scans and a hash join will be used.  Not sure it could be done better? Maybe there is a better example?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case.  Doing as a partition-wise join would be far more efficient (basically, instead of join using a single monstrosity of a hash table, it could use 50 "mini" hash tables; each MEASUREMENT would only join to ADDRESS_ID within same state.  Significantly more efficient in terms of computational overhead as well as parallelization of join operation.

Comment: With a partition reference each partition in the parent table maps to one partition in the child table. If you had such a subpartition reference then each partition in the parent table would map to an unknown number of subpartitions - that is, one subpartition in each (or most) of an unknown number of partitions - in the child table. So you wouldn't get 50 neat mini hash tables really, you'd get a lot more than that? Even in the partition case I'm not sure you'd see any real benefit with your example, you're just trying to second-guess the optimiser.

Comment: Let's leave partition-wise joins aside; consider: SELECT CITY, AVG(MEASUREMENT) FROM MEASUREMENTS  JOIN ADDRESSES USING (ADDRESS_ID) WHERE STATE_CD = 'AL'
GROUP BY CITY; - this would clearly be fastest if measurements were sub-partitioned by STATE_CD and optimizer did full scan of all P_AL subpartitions.